# How to replace a \string with a non-backslashed string in emacs abbrev mode?

Tags: emacs, macros, substitution, tex

My question is motivated by writing TeX in emacs, but is unrelated to the TeX system itself.

My goal is to set up abbreviations in emacs to replace some (TeX) macros with their unicode characters, for example \alpha with α automatically while I'm typing TeX in emacs.

I planned to achieve this using the abbrev system. While the following abbreviation works fine (replaces test with \test):

```
("test" "\\test" nil 0)
```

The abbreviations that could do what I want, i.e.:

```
("\\alpha" "A" nil 0)
```

or

```
("\\\\beta" "B" nil 0)
```

are not applying when I type \alpha or \beta.

(I could sidestep this by replacing "alpha" itself and erasing one preceding character, but I would like to preserve the option of typing alpha without the backslash and not applying this abbrev rule.)

What is the correct form of the abbreviation that replaces \alpha with α?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the property `:regexp` of your abbrev table.

```
(abbrev-table-put <your-abbrev-table> :regexp "\\(\\\\[a-z0-9@]+\\)")
```

The only problem is, in a regexp that is matched looking backwards, you can't have optional characters at the beginning. So, either you change the syntax category of `\` (but then you don't need any special handling of abbrev tables), or you have to choose to have your all abbrevs in this table start with or without a backslash.

But why don't you use an input method to insert unicode characters?

Comment: At least the TeX input method described below is too eager to substitute, thus preventing you to easily type \over, \varepsilon or other TeX macros which are not actually part of the input method. My aim was to find a solution where I can type TeX as always, with the substitution happening without active input from me.

Comment: I see. I use rfc1345, it's really complete and systematic; I recommend you try it. In any case, changing the regexp works, with one caveat (see edited answer).

Answer (score 2):

This already exists. Use the function `set-input-method` and select `TeX`.

Comment: While not an answer to the question itself, this sidesteps the question and allows me to achieve my goal directly. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your solution, is it possible to suggest to emacs a non-eager version of the input-method system?

For example, if I have a abbrev for \\alpha and type \\alphar, nothing gets substituted.

However, if I type \varepsilon in the TeX input-method, I end up with ǎrepsilon because it aggresively matches \va which is in its database.

Comment: I never really played with abbrev